# const parameter vs rvalue parameter pass, when saved internally to the class private variables

Tags: c++, constants

class A has an object that can be shared, but only internally modified

```
class A 
{
public:
   validityClass ** getValidityShared() // I want to make this const return, not sure how to protect a double pointer const signeture
   {
      return &validityShared;
   }
private:
   validityClass * validityShared;
}
```

class B need an access, read for validations, or B class population through its constructor

```
class B
{
   B(A & ainst)
   {
      aValidityShared = ainst.getValidityShared();
   }
private:
   validityClass ** aValidityShared;/// tried to save it as validityClass ** & aValidityShared but I guess its wrong, even though everything worked out
}
```

after B constructor is over, I am no longer need to know anything about A class!

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   A instA;
   B(&instA);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want B intance to have the A shared variable, but without any extra resources, so I tried to save it as an rValue.

1. what do you recommend? (save internally as an rvalue or const
   (double const))
2. how is the const protection for a double pointer?
3. or just never keep it internally saved?

by the way the example is slightly different than what I am using, but it is the same context

and I am asking this question because I am getting some weird warning:
`member initializers for`const char ** classB::xVar`

Comment: Can you be sure the instance of A passed to B's constructor will survive the instance of B? If that is not true, you B instance owns a pointer into deallocated space.

Comment: Class B private pointer will be pointing directly to the private member of class A, however, I want to make the pointer to be const, "pointer&data its pointing to"

Comment: What if the instance of A that owns that private member goes out of scope or is deleted?

Comment: the pointer will be used to initialize the class b only initialy, so pointer is not needed, but later on, the design will be that B manages a bunch of As, so B can get As deleted and managed

Comment: Use "You ain't gonna need it" principle. Don't code for the future. When the time comes for Bs to manage As, that's when you need to think about this pointer. If it's "a bunch" of As, then one pointer is not too useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
validityClass ** getValidityShared() 
    // I want to make this const return, not sure how 
    // to protect a double pointer const signeture
```

You need to add const to the value and the pointers, so to provide real const-correctness that signature would be:

```
validityClass const * const * getValidityShared() const
```

The second pointer need not be const, as that is a value. I placed the `const` on the right, as that is the *right* thing to do, and I believe it makes it more readable.

You could also return a *reference*, in which case you would want:

```
validityClass const * const & getValidityShared() const
```

Comment: is it similar to const validityClass * const * getValidityShared() const?

Comment: @aboody: That would return a pointer to a pointer that cannot be changed to an object that can be changed. The caller could do: `(*getValidityShared())->mutate()` and that will change the `validityClass` object. One of your comments suggests this is not what you want: *I want to make the pointer to be const, "pointer and **data** its pointing to"*